# additional of features decrease the accuracy- random forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I am using sklearn's random forests module to predict a binary target variable based on 166 features.
When I increase the number of dimensions to 175 the accuracy of the model decreases (from accuracy = 0.86 to 0.81 and from recall = 0.37 to 0.32) .

I would expect more data to only make the model more accurate, especially when the added features were with business value.

I built the model using sklearn in python.
Why the new features did not get weight 0 and left the accuracy as it was ?

Comment: Please post your question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you may be "confusing" your model with useless features. MORE FEATURES or MORE DATA WILL NOT ALWAYS MAKE YOUR MODEL BETTER. The new features will also not get weight zero because the model will try hard to use them! Because there are so many (175!), RF is just not able to come back to the previous "pristine" model with better accuracy and recall (maybe these 9 features are really not adding anything useful).

Think about how a decision tree essentially works. These new features will cause some new splits that can worsen the results. Try to work it out from the basics and slowly adding new information always checking the performance. In addition, pay attention to for example the number of features used per split (mtry). For so many features, you would need to have a very high mtry (to allow for a big sample to be considered for every split). Have you considered adding 1 or 2 more and checking how the accuracy responds? Also, don't forget mtry!

Answer (score 0):

More data does not always make the model more accurate. Random forest is a traditional machine learning method where the programmer has to do the feature selection. If the model is given a lot of data but it is bad, then the model will try to make sense out of that bad data too and will end up messing things up. More data is better for neural networks as those networks select the best possible features out of the data on their own.

Also, 175 features is too much and you should definitely look into dimensionality reduction techniques and select the features which are highly correlated with the target. there are several methods in sklearn to do that. You can try PCA if your data is numerical or RFE to remove bad features, etc.